# How can I bit-reflect a byte in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, byte, bit-manipulation

Is there an easy way to bit-reflect a byte variable in Delphi so that the most significant bit (MSB) gets the least significant bit (LSB) and vice versa?

Comment: Lookup table with 16 elements, and flip each nibble (4 bit pair) then combine the nibbles in reverse order.

Comment: @Warren or 256-bytes table and then single XLAT assembler command :-)

Comment: Do you really mean just the high and low bits? Or do you mean to flip all the bits in the byte?

Comment: XLAT is slow.. so slow it is not available any more in x64 opcodes, as far as I remember. On old 8086/80286, XLAT did make sense. But nowadays you have indexed lookup in standard mov opcode, which is faster on modern CPUs. Such a lookup can be coded even in pascal, using an array: if the element size is 1/4/8/16, it will use a dedicated opcode prefix. Asm is not mandatory to write fast code.

Comment: @Warren Doing this for nibbles is silly, as a table for bytes is much faster and simpler and will not use much memory. (I don't think Delphi is used for very small microcontrollers.)

Comment: Easy ways aside, if you can use `pshufb` you can reverse 16 bytes at the same time with a 16-element LUT (doing this for nibbles is not so silly after all). `vpperm`, which is less common, would be easier to use and probably faster though. Only helps if you have a lot of bytes to reverse though.

Comment: @starblue Although I actually searched for a solution in Delphi there is a nice Pascal compiler for small 8bit micro-controllers: [E-LAB](http://www.e-lab.de/AVRco/index_en.html). The nibble-wise solution would make sense there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In code you can do it like this:

```
function ReverseBits(b: Byte): Byte;
var 
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to 8 do
  begin
    Result := (Result shl 1) or (b and 1);
    b := b shr 1;
  end;
end;
```

But a lookup table would be much more efficient, and only consume 256 bytes of memory.

```
function ReverseBits(b: Byte): Byte; inline;
const
  Table: array [Byte] of Byte = (
    0,128,64,192,32,160,96,224,16,144,80,208,48,176,112,240,
    8,136,72,200,40,168,104,232,24,152,88,216,56,184,120,248,
    4,132,68,196,36,164,100,228,20,148,84,212,52,180,116,244,
    12,140,76,204,44,172,108,236,28,156,92,220,60,188,124,252,
    2,130,66,194,34,162,98,226,18,146,82,210,50,178,114,242,
    10,138,74,202,42,170,106,234,26,154,90,218,58,186,122,250,
    6,134,70,198,38,166,102,230,22,150,86,214,54,182,118,246,
    14,142,78,206,46,174,110,238,30,158,94,222,62,190,126,254,
    1,129,65,193,33,161,97,225,17,145,81,209,49,177,113,241,
    9,137,73,201,41,169,105,233,25,153,89,217,57,185,121,249,
    5,133,69,197,37,165,101,229,21,149,85,213,53,181,117,245,
    13,141,77,205,45,173,109,237,29,157,93,221,61,189,125,253,
    3,131,67,195,35,163,99,227,19,147,83,211,51,179,115,243,
    11,139,75,203,43,171,107,235,27,155,91,219,59,187,123,251,
    7,135,71,199,39,167,103,231,23,151,87,215,55,183,119,247,
    15,143,79,207,47,175,111,239,31,159,95,223,63,191,127,255
  );
begin
  Result := Table[b];
end;
```

This is more than 10 times faster than the version of the code that operates on individual bits.

---

Finally, I don't normally like to comment too negatively on accepted answers when I have a competing answer. In this case there are very serious problems with the answer that you accepted that I would like to state clearly for you and also for any future readers.

You accepted @Arioch's answer at the time when it contained the same Pascal code as can be seen in this answer, together with two assembler versions. It turns out that those assembler versions are much slower than the Pascal version. They are twice as slow as the Pascal code.

It is a common fallacy that converting high level code to assembler results in faster code. If you do it badly then you can easily produce code that runs more slowly than the code emitted by the compiler. There are times when it is worth writing code in assembler but you must not ever do so without proper benchmarking.

What is particularly egregious about the use of assembler here is that it is so obvious that the table based solution will be exceedingly fast. It's hard to imagine how that could be significantly improved upon.

Comment: Good interview question fodder.

Comment: Still, lookup table would require your function for populaton :-)

Comment: +1 this is a very good option if those 256 bytes of memory can be traded for speed, I now I would (:

Comment: The LUT version is indeed a lot faster and would be my choice too. +1

Comment: Remove loop, repeat `RCR` `RCL` 8 times to get linear code without branches and you will beat pascal code, probably you can also win replacing bytes (`AL`, `DL`) by full native 32-bit registers (EAX, EDX). Assembler is fun. Sure you can't beat LUT version.

Comment: @serg Can you prove that? I'm not saying that you are wrong. My point remains that optimsing without timing is pointless and harmful. If you are prepared to unroll the asm then you can equally unroll the pascal. LUT wins.

Comment: @Serg Unrolling the asm loop makes that code go faster. But it's still slower than the Pascal in my answer. Unrolling the loop in that Pascal restores the factor of 2 perf difference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure timings are critical for optimization because less code does not mean more speed. I think you should also use full 32-bit registers instead of bytes and replace `RCR`'s by `SHR`'s to remove unnecessary dependence of commands via carry bit.

Comment: @Serg I don't think *I* need to do anything. It's Arioch that thinks asm is good here. My points are conceptual rather than the specifics of this algo. The details aren't interesting to me. The high level principles are.

Comment: My solution shows it does not have to be a LUT to be fast. `MirrorByte` is tiny bit faster in 32 bit and some percent slower in 64 bit.

Comment: @LURD I commenting here for future readers, but that conclusion turns out to be false. No bit by bit solution can compete with LUT.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, updated my answer. The compiler was doing a better job at optimising than I could imagine.

Comment: @Serg i tested on AMD Phenom2 - i can't see difference between using 8-bit and 32-but registers, i also cannot see difference between using different registers or different 8-bit parts of one register. Really, interference of hardware optimizations and compiler optimizations are fun and unpredictable. Removing one redundant (mindlessly copied from Pascal source) line from my ASM code i made it 2 times faster :-)

Comment: "No bit by bit solution can compete with LUT". Well, a bit of arithmetic did the trick. Not faster than LUT generally, but in one of my tests it was. A challenge is always fun :-)

Comment: @LURD if you're curious i wonder if one can devise a test, that would measure those functions in a contrast light, but would not let the whole LUT be stored in CPU L1 cache. Because actual LUTs are bound by RAM or at least L2/L3 cache latency.

Comment: @Arioch'The, writing tests that involves expertise on CPU cache is out of my league I'm afraid. But feel free to have a go!

Comment: @LURD I am not that clever and not that crazy - but take a look at call elimination, done Delphi way (in my answer) :-)  And good night and good weekend!

Answer (score 14):

```
function BitFlip(B: Byte): Byte;
const
  N: array[0..15] of Byte = (0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15);
begin
  Result := N[B div 16] or N[B mod 16] shl 4;
end;
```

Comment: That is like Warren said. Modelled after IntToHex :-) But actually i cannot see the point in this. For speed-limiting massive use one should use 256-bytes lookup table and for occasional relaxed use no table is needed at all. This computation+lookup approach looks  fitting neither of usecases.

Comment: @Arioch'The My only point here was: it's Friday afternoon. :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 13):

```
function ByteReverseLoop(b: byte): byte;
var i: integer;
begin
  Result := 0; // actually not needed, just to make compiler happy

  for i := 1 to 8 do
  begin
    Result := Result shl 1; 
    if Odd(b) then Result := Result or 1;
    b := b shr 1;
  end;
end;
```

If speed is important, then you can use lookup table. You feel it once on program start and then you just take a value from table. Since you're only needing to map byte to byte, that would take 256x1=256 bytes of memory. And given recent Delphi versions support inline functions, that would provide for both speed, readability and reliability (incapsulating array lookup in the function you may be sure you would not change the values due to some typo)

```
Var ByteReverseLUT: array[byte] of byte;

function ByteReverse(b: byte): byte; inline;
begin Result := ByteReverseLUT[b] end;

{Unit/program initialization}
var b: byte;
    for b := Low(ByteReverseLUT) to High(ByteReverseLUT) 
        do ByteReverseLUT[b] := ByteReverseLoop(b);
```

---

Speed comparison of several implementations that were mentioned on this forum.
 *AMD Phenom2 x710 / Win7 x64 / Delphi XE2 32-bit {$O+}*

```
Pascal AND original:       12494
Pascal AND reversed:       33459
Pascal IF original:        46829
Pascal IF reversed:        45585

       Asm SHIFT 1:        15802
       Asm SHIFT 2:        15490
       Asm SHIFT 3:        16212

         Asm AND 1:        19408
         Asm AND 2:        19601
         Asm AND 3:        19802
```

Pascal AND unrolled:        10052
    Asm Shift unrolled:         4573
           LUT, called:         3192
   Pascal math, called:         4614

http://pastebin.ca/2304708

*Note: LUT (lookup table) timings are probably rather optimistic here. Due to running in tight loop the whole table was sucked into L1 CPU cache. In real computations this function most probably would be called much less frequently and L1 cache would not keep the table entirely.*

---

Pascal inlined function calls result are bogus - Delphi did not called them, detecting they had no side-effects. But funny - the timings were different.

```
      Asm Shift unrolled:         4040
             LUT, called:         3011
            LUT, inlined:          977
         Pascal unrolled:        10052
  Pas. unrolled, inlined:          849
     Pascal math, called:         4614
    Pascal math, inlined:         6517
```

And below the explanation:

```
Project1.dpr.427: d := BitFlipLUT(i)
0044AC45 8BC3             mov eax,ebx
0044AC47 E89CCAFFFF       call BitFlipLUT

Project1.dpr.435: d := BitFlipLUTi(i)

Project1.dpr.444: d := MirrorByte(i);
0044ACF8 8BC3             mov eax,ebx
0044ACFA E881C8FFFF       call MirrorByte

Project1.dpr.453: d := MirrorByteI(i);
0044AD55 8BC3             mov eax,ebx

Project1.dpr.460: d := MirrorByte7Op(i);
0044ADA3 8BC3             mov eax,ebx
0044ADA5 E8AEC7FFFF       call MirrorByte7Op

Project1.dpr.462: d := MirrorByte7OpI(i);
0044ADF1 0FB6C3           movzx eax,bl
```

All calls to inlined functions were eliminated.
Yet about passing the parameters Delphi made three different decisions:

1. For the 1st call it eliminated parameter passing together with function call
2. For the 2nd call it kept parameter passing, despite function was not called
3. For the 3rd call it kept changed parameter passing, which proved longer then function call itself! Weird! :-)

Comment: Assembler just sets you maintenence work for future targets and the performance is still poor when compared to lookup. Perhaps you should advise not to use asm.

Comment: @David, i'd say not to use ASM as the only implementation.

Comment: It should not be called `BitFlip`. Flipping is changing 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. But this changes position. Reflection is quite a reasonable name. Also, the x86 asm is wrong. It throws AVs. When you fix the x86 asm version you find that it's 2.5 times slower than the Pascal in my answer. For x64 the ratio is 1.8.

Comment: And the lookup table is more than 10 times faster than any 1 to 8 bit at a time variant

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I also mentioned the lookup table, even in question-level comments before ur post. However i'm definitely against hardcoding "magic values", as in your recent edit. Lookup table should be calculated on program initialization, if it is really needed.

Comment: I was thinking along the lings of flipping the coin or reversi piece. Well, this line would end with ByteFlip, my bad. But "ReflectByte" was not any better ,since reflection usually meant RTTI in IT :-)

Comment: Feel free to build your table at runtime if you prefer. I still don't understand the point of the asm in your answer. Why did you include it? Why would it ever be useful?

Comment: Funny thing, but ASM speed is predictable. Let's take your function and just change shift direction to the opposite - that should not influence its speed, yes ? Or not ?

Comment: I'd measure rather than try to predict. You seem to be side-stepping my direct question.

Comment: The point is that my background is coming from making library that 1) i have no control how can be run (compiler version, options) and 2) actual computations were not constant byte-to-byte mappings, LUT would hardly be helping there. What about "I'd measure rather than try to predict" - sorry, i do not think so. I think you startd measuring only after i put ASM code there. If to talk about one man applications, then those ASM functions - for me personally - were not harder to read and understand than extra indirection level introduced by LUT.

Comment: I measured as soon as I got to a computer. My original answer was written from a train. You on the other hand wrote very slow asm which attracted lots of upvotes and an accept, and only measured a day later under duress. It's likely that performance isn't even important here. This is another case of premature optimisation. And a particularly fine example of the pitfalls.

Comment: The pitfall was to copy "Result := 0" redundant line to the assembler. It made the function twice as slow...
And u managed to hit the optimization sweet spot, lucky you.
you measured as u saw my code, if i would not put it - i doubt u would devise ur own asm implementation to measure it.

Comment: The pitfall was to write asm for no good reason and not to measure it. The pitfall was to make a code only answer with no explanation. And yes, I would not have measured if I hadn't seen your poor asm versions. My intuition suggested that they might be slow. If you had measured I would not have. But you missed that step. The most important step.

Answer (score 8):

Using brute force can be simple and effective.

This routine is NOT <strike>on</strike> par with David's LUT solution.

**Update**

Added array of byte as input and result assigned to array of byte as well.
This shows better performance for the LUT solution.

```
function MirrorByte(b : Byte) : Byte;  inline;
begin
  Result :=
    ((b and $01) shl 7) or
    ((b and $02) shl 5) or
    ((b and $04) shl 3) or
    ((b and $08) shl 1) or
    ((b and $10) shr 1) or
    ((b and $20) shr 3) or
    ((b and $40) shr 5) or
    ((b and $80) shr 7);
end;
```

**Update 2**

Googling a little, found [`BitReverseObvious`](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious).

```
function MirrorByte7Op(b : Byte) : Byte;  inline;
begin
  Result :=
    {$IFDEF WIN64}  // This is slightly better in x64 than the code in x32
    (((b * UInt64($80200802)) and UInt64($0884422110)) * UInt64($0101010101)) shr 32;
    {$ENDIF}
    {$IFDEF WIN32}
    ((b * $0802 and $22110) or (b * $8020 and $88440)) * $10101 shr 16;
    {$ENDIF}
end;
```

This one is closer to the LUT solution, even faster in one test.

> To sum up, **MirrorByte7Op()** is 5-30% slower than LUT in 3 of the tests, 5% faster in one test.

Code to benchmark:

```
uses
  System.Diagnostics;

const 
  cBit : Byte = $AA;
  cLoopMax = 1000000000;
var
  sw : TStopWatch;
  arrB : array of byte;
  i : Integer;

begin
  SetLength(arrB,cLoopMax);
  for i := 0 TO Length(arrB) - 1 do
    arrB[i]:= System.Random(256);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    b := b;
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('Loop             ',b:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    b := ReflectBits(arrB[i]); 
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('RB array in:     ',b:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    b := MirrorByte(arrB[i]);
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('MB array in:     ',b:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    b := MirrorByte7Op(arrB[i]);
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('MB7Op array in : ',arrB[0]:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    arrB[i] := ReflectBits(arrB[i]);
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('RB array in/out: ',arrB[0]:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    arrB[i]:= MirrorByte(arrB[i]);
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('MB array in/out: ',arrB[0]:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  for i := 0 to Pred(cLoopMax) do
  begin
    arrB[i]:= MirrorByte7Op(arrB[i]);
  end;
  sw.Stop;
  WriteLn('MB7Op array in/out: ',arrB[0]:3,' ',sw.ElapsedMilliSeconds);

  ReadLn;

end.
```

Result of benchmark (XE3, i7 CPU 870):

```
                                32 bit     64 bit
--------------------------------------------------
Byte assignment (= empty loop)   599 ms    2117 ms
MirrorByte    to byte, array in 6991 ms    8746 ms
MirrorByte7Op to byte, array in 1384 ms    2510 ms
ReverseBits   to byte, array in  945 ms    2119 ms
--------------------------------------------------
ReverseBits   array in/out      1944 ms    3721 ms
MirrorByte7Op array in/out      1790 ms    3856 ms
BitFlipNibble array in/out      1995 ms    6730 ms
MirrorByte    array in/out      7157 ms    8894 ms
ByteReverse   array in/out     38246 ms   42303 ms
```

---

I added some of the other proposals in the last part of the table (all inlined). It is probably most fair to test in a loop with an array in and an array as result. `ReverseBits` (LUT) and `MirrorByte7Op` are comparable in speed followed by `BitFlipNibble` (LUT) which underperforms a bit in x64.

Note: I added a new algorithm for the x64 bit part of `MirrorByte7Op`. It makes better use of the 64 bit registers and has fewer instructions.

Comment: In my benchmark program, this code is 7 times slower than LUT on x86 and 3 times slower than LUT on x64. Not sure why LUT is so much slower on x64 than x86. My benchmark reverses bits on a 1GB array of bytes. The possible byte patterns are uniformly distributed within the array.

Comment: Included my simple benchmark. Both routines are independent of byte patterns. I will try with an array of bytes.

Comment: Look under the debugger and you should see that your benchmark does nothing. Because you never read the value returned from `b`, the compiler simply optimises it away! You are just timing an empty for loop. Sorry to burst your bubble. By the way, I like your code. It's rather nicely done in my view. It's faster than the Pascal version in my answer. LUT is still king though. I defy anyone to beat that!

Comment: I wonder if you are planning to fix the benchmark in this answer. I don't like the misleading nature of this answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I did take a reference to the result, but forgot to show it, sorry for the confusion. As you see from the result, if an input array is used, 7 times in favour to LUT in x86. If array is used in/out, it's a factor of 3.5. Difference is smaller on x64.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, removed the static assignments from the tests. Even if I took reference to the result, using a static input did not give a reliable test. The compiler precalculated the function call, did not expect that.

Comment: Good for the compiler!! Benchmarking can be really tricky. Always worth stepping through in CPU window to see what code actually runs! Thanks for the update.

Comment: "You are just timing an empty for loop" funny thins - that is wrong. Copiler eliminates the function's body - but not the passing of function's parameters. And that leads to different timings on "eliminated" functions :-)  Surely truely empty loops would be times equally.

Comment: @Arioch'The It was true at the time I wrote that comment. But this answer has been edited. Perhaps it's time for you to stop digging and accept that you got this one wrong. We all make mistakes. I know I do. The trick is to recognise that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, updated test results with some more of the other proposals. I'm quite happy with the performance of `MirrorByte7Op`. I guess in real code the results can vary, but I can't predict which algorithm would be the optimum.

Comment: MirrorByte7Op is rather cute. My benchmark has is twice as slow in x86, 10% slower in x64. What I still don't understand is why LUT is so much slower in x64 than x86. It's four times slower in my benchmark.