# Manipulating bits of byte vars in Delphi

Tags: delphi, byte, bit

I am pulling data from a .txt file byte by byte using delphi. For each byte, I need to swap the beginning and the ending bits of that byte. I've been searching google for hours but I can't find any reference about manipulating bits inside byte vars in delphi. Any ideas?

Comment: Quickest way is to use a lookup table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
b := (b and $7E) or (b shr 7) or (b shl 7);
```

First we keep the middle 6 bits, then swaps the MSB and the LSB bits in register shift operations.

Bit manipulation in Delphi is fun.
There are many options, and this is a straight forward solution.
David proposes a LUT solution which can be faster (only by a tiny bit though).

There was an interesting similar question about bit-reflecting a whole byte, see [`How can I bit-reflect a byte in Delphi?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14400845/576719).

Comment: This is *the* solution. The first operand is b wihtout its MSB and LSB, the second operand is the initial MSB (now at the LSB position) while the third operand is the initial LSB (now at the MSB position). Of course, the `or`ed result is `b` with the MSB-LSB swap.

Comment: Also, if you would go for a look-up table, you can use the one-liner above to generate that table!

Comment: Perfect answer by LU RD! Thanks for the explanation Andreas!